# Is such a subset of irrationals exists? (Question related to CH)

Tags: set-theory

On Wikipedia page of **continuum hypothesis (CH)**. It is given that, following is an equivalent statement of continuum hypothesis.

> any subset of the real numbers is finite, is countably infinite, or has the same cardinality as the real numbers

Now, **If** CH is False! Then, there must be some subset $S\subset\mathbb{R}$ whose cardinality is strictly lies between that of integers and the real numbers.

Hence such a set $S$ must have following properties:

(1) $S\not\subseteq\mathbb{Q}$ (Since $\mathbb{Q}$ is countable)

(2) $S$ must contains more than countably many irrationals (otherwise it will again countable)

(3) $S$ cannot contains uncountably many irrationals (otherwise it will be uncountable)

So by (2) & (3). **Can we say that CH is reduced (equivalent) to saying that**,

> Is there is any subset $S$ of irrationals $\mathbb{Q}^c$ which is neither countable nor uncountable?

If yes! Then How could be it possible that, such a set $S$ exist?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "how could it be possible that, such a set $S$ exist?" You answered this yourself: this set exists if the continuum hypothesis is false.

Comment: @morrowmh I have asked something else before that, Is CH is equivalent to the statement that mentioned in the last part of the post?

Comment: Your (3) is garbled: "$S$ cannot contains uncountably many irrationals (otherwise it will be uncountable)" should be "$S$ cannot contain **continuum many** irrationals." Of course we **do** want $S$, a putative counterexample to CH, to be uncountable.

Comment: @NoahSchweber sir, yes. So you mean $S$ may be uncountable but it's cardinality less than that of continuum? (Is it possible?)

Comment: @GeneralMathematics That's exactly what a counterexample to CH would be, so it's possible - and indeed, happens - iff CH fails.

Comment: You are equating "uncountable" = "cardinality of the rationals" when all it actually means is "not countable".  Yes the reals are uncountable but it is not that only cardinality that is uncountable.  If then CH is false then $S$ would be uncountable but not the same cardinality of $\mathbb R$.  That may be hard to imagine but it's not contradictory.

Comment: @NoahSchweber sir. Thank you for your comments. Further, When I read the your last comment, "so it's possible and Indeed happens", I was very excited! Until **iff CH fails**

Comment: @fleablood sir, yes I got it. $S$ would be uncountable but it's cardinality will be less than $\mathbb{R}$. But really such a set exist? (Though there exists a set which is uncountable but whose cardinality is not cardinality of continuum (it is greater than cardinality of continuum) for example: The power set of real numbers $P(\mathbb{R})$. It's cardinality is $2^c > c$ )

Comment: "But really such a set exist?"  No-one has ever found one.  And if we believe the Continuum Hypothesis, then no, such a set *doesn't* exist.  But if we believe the CH is false then set a set must exist.  THe continuum hypothesis is *precisely* the statement "Such a set does not exist".

Comment: Please don't use words like "weird" or "crazy" in the title. This is a "personal interpretation", but not a mathematical term.

Comment: @DietrichBurde ok sir. I will not use such words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, $CH$ hypothesizes that there’s a set which is ***uncountable*** yet of cardinality less than $\mathbb{R}$ (an uncountable cardinality *in between* $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{R}$)

Due to the work of Godel and Cohen, we know that the truth or falsity of $CH$ is in a sense indeterminate, because there are models of $ZFC$ in which $CH$ is true and models of $ZFC$ in which $CH$ is false.

One might wonder if it’s possible to write down an explicit “formula” specifying a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ which violates $CH$: As far as I know this is not possible.

Comment: Sir, can you provide any references to second and third paragraphs of your answer.

Comment: See Theorem 1.1 and Theorem 1.2 in [this article](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/continuum-hypothesis/)

Comment: Regarding the third paragraph, I don’t have a reference for you. I’m not aware of any such “formula” and I *suspect* it cannot exist, but I don’t know enough to say for sure.

Comment: Sir, I mean reference for the last line, "this is not possible"

Comment: What I mean is that despite the existence of models of $ZFC$ containing sets that violate $CH$, it is not possible (as far as I know) to individually identify such a set by writing down an explicit “formula” that defines it. However I don’t have a specific reference for this. For learning more about set theory in general, Enderton’s *Elements of Set Theory* is not a bad place to start.